# Going through 3 arrays in order with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this is just a simple problem, but I don't know where I went wrong. 
I have 3 arryas

Names:

```
Alex, John, Sam
```

Hobby

```
Baseball, Hockey, Golf
```

City

```
Sudbury, Toronto, Ottawa
```

I've set up the following code, but the 2nd and 3rd arrays don't change.

```
for(var n=0;n<names.length;n++){  
var h=0;t<hobby.length;h++;
var c=0;c<city.length;c++;


alert (names[n]);
alert (hobby[h]);
alert (city[c]);
}
```

How do I set them up to cycle in order?

Comment: Ditch `var h=0;t<hobby.length;h++;` and `var c=0;c<city.length;c++;` and use `alert(hobby[n])` and `alert(city[n])`

Comment: What do you expect the output to do?

Comment: Consider this structure: `[ { name: 'Alex', hobby: 'Baseball', city: 'Sudbury' }, { ... }, ... ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var h=0;t<hobby.length;h++;
var c=0;c<city.length;c++;
```

These two lines do almost nothing to your code. In each iteration, both variables are set to `0` and are then incremented by one. So, when coming to the `alert()`s, they're always `1`.

Assuming, that always the items with the same index relate to each other, this will give you the respective sets:

```
for(var n=0;n<names.length;n++){  
  alert (names[n]);
  alert (hobby[n]);
  alert (city[n]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I kept reading the answers they became easier and easier to implement. This one is great!

Answer (score 1):

You should get those into a proper data structure before doing anything else..

```
var people = [];

for( var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i ){
    people.push({
        name: names[i],
        hobby: hobby[i],
        city: city[i]
    });
}
```

Then:

```
for( var i = 0; i < people.length; ++i ) {
    var person = people[i];
    alert( person.name );
    alert( person.hobby );
    alert( person.city );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all the same length, and there are no missing entries, you could:

```
for(var n=0;n<names.length && n<hobby.length && n<city.length;n++){
  alert (names[n]);
  alert (hobby[n]);
  alert (city[n]);
}
```